# Replacing string inside a file with VBS And batching

Tags: bash, file, batch-file, replace, vbscript

I am trying to build a batch file using VBS that will replace certain string inside a file. Its working but the problem is i want to make the station variable to indicate on the dir since the file exists in some folders.

here is what i did:

the VBS code:

```
Const ForReading = 1    
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewText  'WriteLine adds extra CR/LF
objFile.Close
```

and here is the run batch code:

```
    :input
@echo off
CLS
ECHO   #############################################
ECHO   #                                           #
ECHO   #  1 - AM                                   #
ECHO   #  2 - PM                                   #
Echo   #  3 - Exit                                 #
ECHO   #                                           #
ECHO   #############################################


SET O=""
SET STATION =""
SET /P STATION=Set Your STATION number:
SET PATH ="C:\Envfile\%STATION%\Envfile.env"
SET /P O=Set Your Choice And Press Enter:
ECHO Loading .........
IF %O%==1 GOTO AM
IF %O%==2 GOTO PM
IF %O%==3 GOTO Exit
IF %O%=="" GOTO input
goto done

:AM

    cscript replace.vbs %PATH% "PM" "AM"
goto done

:PM

    cscript replace.vbs %PATH% "AM" "PM"
goto done


ELSE 
GOTO input
```

as you can see the user passes the "station number var" at the beginning of the code and I want it to endicate on the Envfile.env file that located in folder named after the station number(for ex:1123).

for some reason it's not working.

help?

Comment: Remove the space between your variable name and the equals symbol in your SET statement..  I would also not use PATH as a variable name either.  Use tpath or something.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this, Apperantly the path of the vbscript compiler was erased from the computer's enviorment path.

Comment: That depends if you were using: `SET PATH ="C:\Envfile\%STATION%\Envfile.env"` or `SET PATH="C:\Envfile\%STATION%\Envfile.env"` to SET the PATH variable.  If you overwrote the SYSTEM PATH variable then yes that is your problem with it not finding cscript.  But you also have to realize that **%path %** is not the same as **%path%**.

Comment: You should provide details for your solution; please remember that SO is there for helping people to find solutions for programming issues; if somebody has the same problem and comes to this thread, he will be quite disappointed, don't you think?